# Why are our olives getting moldy?

Tags: storage-method

Our family consumes a lot of olives. About 5 years ago, we started buying the 55oz cans of Lindsey sliced black olives. We put them in about 7 separate plastic containers (Hillshire Farms sliced deli meat containers) and then refrigerate them. As we finish off a container, we open a new one. We've done this for years without a problem.

Of the last 3 cans, though, by the time we get to the third container of olives, they're starting to mold. All the containers of remaining olives are molding. Why would this suddenly start happening? We haven't really changed anything, so I can only assume that Lindsey has changed something.

Is there something we can do to prevent this?

At the rate we consume olives, it's just ridiculous to buy those tiny little cans. Even if we only go through two of the containers before they go bad, we're saving money, but we hate the idea of wasting all those olives.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You say you haven’t ‘really’ changed anything, does that mean you’ve ‘sort of’ changed things? Have you changed dish soap, has the design/materials of the containers changed (assuming you haven’t been using the same ones for 5 years. Are you using the olives as fast as always?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. As far as we know, we haven't changed anything. We buy our olives at the same store. We store them in the same containers we've always stored them in.
After we got the mold problem, I noticed that the mold was really hard to wash out of the containers. The last couple of times, I've really scrubbed them down well and then run them through the dishwasher hoping that would eliminate all the mold and spores.
We even tried using new containers that that we've never used before, but the problem persists.

Comment: In 5 yrs, it's very likely that Lindsay has changed something in their process. If you are very interested, you ought to inquire with them. If they answer, you might get an idea how to fix the problem

Comment: Have you been using the same fridge all that time? Arranged the same? Defrosted regularly? Have you knocked the temperature control? It might be worth checking the temperature is what you expect it to be.

Comment: @ChrisH, I hadn't considered that. We did replace our refrigerator a while back. I'm fairly certain the problem started a good bit after that, but perhaps not. I've tried lowering the temperature in the refrigerator a bit to see if that helps.

Comment: @LorelC. Thanks for the tip. I've e-mailed Lindsey to ask their advice.

Comment: Also next time you open a can, you could try freezing one container. How well olives freeze depends on how exactly they're prepared but they might be good

Comment: How long is it from when you open a can to when you see the mold? Also, are you sure the containers remain airtight? My guess would be that deli meat containers were not meant for long term storage. Maybe buy one actual storage container (Rubbermaid, Glad or something like that) and see if you have the same experience.

Comment: Just checking .. you are covering the olives with the brine they were canned in? You shouldn't strain them out..

Comment: @user3169 They're air tight. We use these same containers for a number of foods and we've been using them for the olives for years without issue.

Comment: @ChrisH I might try that. I vaguely recall that we tried freezing them in the past and they got mushy when thawed, but can't hurt to try again.

Comment: @RobinBetts Yes, we separate out the olives with a slotted spoon and then pour the brine equally among the containers so that they're all covered.

Comment: Also, just in case someone asks, no, it's not coagulated olive oil on the olives. It's a pale green mold.

Comment: Also while you are communicating with Lindsay, you might ask them what the expected "freshness" of the olives in the 55oz. cans is after opening. Even if this worked in the past, you might be exceeding it, since large cans are likely intended for food service where they would be used much more quickly. I don't think you have stated how long it takes you to use up 7 containers.

Comment: How about laying some plastic wrap on top of them in the container? If the mold is in the air, keeping oxygen away from them would prevent the contamination.

Comment: Finally, regarding the fridge temp., use a suitable thermometer and periodically check it. The temperature does vary up and down due to activity and defrosting. The temp. control itself isn't helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Change your olive storage to glass jars and plastic lids. I use Bell jars and buy the plastic lids where I buy the jars; Walmart or hardware store, during canning season. The glass jars can be sterilized, if mold forms on the food. Plastic can never really be clean once the mold starts. Toss the plastic.